# Reset Internet Proxy Remembered Account on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, cache

When you go to the internet across a proxy server, windows ask you for your username and password and you can tell it that remember that account and password forever.

My problem is that I need to change that password because I have a different account now.

The deal is with windows password requirements, not with the browser password requirement. On chrome work ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Control panel\User Accounts\Advanced\Manage passwords.  Select the entry for the proxy server, click `Properties` and then change your user name and password.

Comment: Hi, thanks that was very useful. My problem was solve. On windows 8 is a little different. The option is under UserAccounts\Admin Credentials.